# How to scrape the required data using python requests?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to scrape the data for NYC daycares from https://a816-healthpsi.nyc.gov/ChildCare/SearchAction2.do

I tried using requests.get and requests.post, however the data it scrapes does not have the table of daycares as we can see on the website once we click the search button.

## Using requests.get

```
import requests
url=requests.get('https://a816-healthpsi.nyc.gov/ChildCare/SearchAction2.do? 
pager.offset=10')
if url.status_code==200:

   response = url.text
   print(url.text)
```

## Using requests.post

```
url2='https://a816-healthpsi.nyc.gov/ChildCare/SearchAction2.do'
payload={'pager.offset':'30'}
r1=requests.post(url2, data=payload)
print(r1.text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://a816-healthpsi.nyc.gov/ChildCare/SearchAction2.do'
payload = 'linkPK=0&pageroffset=0&getNewResult=true&progTypeValues=&search=1&facilityName=&borough=&permitNo=&neighborhood=&building=&street=&zipCode='

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"}
    s.headers.update({'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})
    htmldoc = s.post(URL, data = payload)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(htmldoc.content, "lxml")
    table = soup.find("table", {'id': 'tech-companies'})
    for items in table.find_all("tr"):
        data = [' '.join(item.text.split()) for item in items.find_all("td")]
        print(data)
```

Partial output:

```
['"THE STUDIO SCHOOL"', 'Child Care - Pre School', '117 WEST 95TH STREET', '10025', '212-678-2416', 'Permitted']
['1199 FUTURE OF AMERICA LEARNING CENTER', 'Camp', '2514 CRESTON AVENUE', '10468', '718-562-2915', 'In-Renewal']
['1199 S E I U / EMPLOYER CHILD CARE CORPORATION', 'Child Care - Infants/Toddlers', '2500 CRESTON AVENUE', '10468', '718-562-2915', 'Permitted']
```